# update query using `CASE WHEN` not working when trigger fired in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, case, plpgsql, database-trigger

I try to use a `CASE WHEN` condition to an update query in PostgreSQL.

The query I am doing is :

```sql
if new.bts_trx_gc = 'Terminé' then
        update stt set stt_doe_gc_bts = (case when old.bts_trx_gc <> new.bts_trx_gc then 'Demandé' else stt_doe_gc_bts end) where stt_id = new.bts_id;
        raise info 'test est un test';
    end if;
```

The trigger fire every time as I can see the `raise info` in the consol. But the update does not work.

This query is to make sure when a user is updating a field through a web interface, the update fire only if `old.bts_trx_gc <> new.bts_trx_gc`.
Because it may happens the web interface even if the `bts_trx_gc` value is not modified, a query with `bts_trx_gc = Terminé` is sent. And I only want to fire the update when this field goes from something to `Terminé` only.

Considering the query above, What I am trying to do is if the `IF` condition is true and `old.bts_trx_gc <> new.bts_trx_gc` then `bts_trx_gc = Demandé` else keep same value.

Here the how trigger function :

```sql
create or replace function after_update_bts_trx_gc() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin

    if new.bts_trx_gc = 'Terminé' then
        update stt set stt_doe_gc_bts = (case when old.bts_trx_gc <> new.bts_trx_gc then 'Demandé' else stt_doe_gc_bts end) where stt_id = new.bts_id;
        raise info 'test est un test';
    end if;

    return new;

end;
$$;
```

And here the trigger :

```sql
create trigger after_update_bts_trx_gc
    after update
    on etude_bts
    for each row
execute procedure after_update_bts_trx_gc();
```

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an `IF` to conditionally run the UPDATE, not a CASE expression. This has the added benefit, that you don't run unneeded UPDATEs.

If `bts_trx_gc` can contain null values you should use `is distinct from` rather than `<>` to properly deal with NULL values.

```
create or replace function after_update_bts_trx_gc() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
  if new.bts_trx_gc = 'Terminé' and old.bts_trx_gc IS DISTINCT FROM new.bts_trx_gc then
    UPDATE stt 
       set stt_doe_gc_bts = 'Demandé'
    WHERE stt_id = new.bts_id;

    raise info 'test est un test';
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$;
```

---

This was my original answer where I overlooked the fact that the UPDATE targeted a different table. I am leaving it for reference though.

<strike>Don't use UPDATE to change the row in a trigger. Use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger and assign the value to the `new` row when the condition is met:</strike>

```
create or replace function after_update_bts_trx_gc() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
  if new.bts_trx_gc = 'Terminé' and old.bts_trx_gc <> new.bts_trx_gc then
    new.stt_doe_gc_bts := 'Demandé';
    raise info 'test est un test';
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$;
```

But you need a BEFORE trigger to make that work:

```
create trigger after_update_bts_trx_gc
    BEFORE update
    on etude_bts
    for each row
execute procedure after_update_bts_trx_gc();
```

It would be even more efficient to not fire the trigger at all, if the column doesn't change:

```
create trigger after_update_bts_trx_gc
    BEFORE update 
    on etude_bts
    for each row
    when (old.bts_trx_gc <> new.bts_trx_gc)
execute procedure after_update_bts_trx_gc();
```

Comment: OP has to use update in the trigger. The table being updated, sst, is not the same table the trigger is firing on, etrude_bts.

Comment: Thank you for all the informations. I agree with you when you're talking about `IS DISCTINCT FROM` as I noticed I have this problem only when `old.bts_trx_gc` is null . Otherwise @Belayer is right about using `UPDATE` as I don't update a column from the same table.

Comment: @Belayer: oops, I didn't see that. But still I think using an IF would be better than a CASE expression inside the UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN doesn't work in a trigger for me(always returns true on the first WHEN):

```
myTag = '[' || TG_TABLE_NAME ||
    CASE WHEN TG_TABLE_NAME = 'scac_proformat'
        THEN
        CASE WHEN tg_op IN ('UPDATE','INSERT')
            THEN coalesce(NEW.format_type,'P')
            ELSE coalesce(OLD.format_type,'P')
        END
    ELSE ''
    END
    || ']';
```

This way it works right:

```
IF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'scac_proformat'
    THEN
        myTag = '[' || TG_TABLE_NAME ||
            CASE WHEN tg_op IN ('UPDATE','INSERT')
                    THEN coalesce(NEW.format_type,'P')
                    ELSE coalesce(OLD.format_type,'P')
            END
            || ']';
    END IF;     
    IF TG_TABLE_NAME != 'scac_proformat'
    THEN
        myTag = '[' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ']';
    END IF;
```

I am not sure about inner CASE ;)